# Flutter webivew how to set local storage

Tags: local-storage, android-webview, flutter

My Flutter application flow works like this:

1. User logins
2. If login successfully, server returns a token
3. Set token to local storage in webview
4. Open `Webview` **fullscreen** to a specific URL

I am using [this Webview plugin](https://github.com/dart-flitter/flutter_webview_plugin). The sample code shows that it supports local storage (it has a `withLocalStorage` option) but does not show how to use it.

I tried:

1. Create new `FlutterWebviewPlugin` instance
2. Set local storage on the newly-created instance by calling method `evalJavascript`
3. call `launch` on the instance, set `withJavascript`, `withLocalStorage` to `true` and launched it to a URL;

   ```
   //1
   final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
   //2
   flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("window.localStorage.setItem('token','SOMETOKEN')");
   //3
   flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(
       "https://SOMEURL",
       withLocalStorage: true,
       withJavascript: true);
   ```

If I correctly set the local storage, the `Webview` would show account page; otherwise a login page (which was what happened)

I also note that the `evalJavascript` invocation doesn't seem to work. Also, changing order of step 2 and step 3 doesn't change anything.

Note that I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495293/flutter-webview-plugin-how-to-handle-local-storage-variables). The answer provided doesn't show how to set the local storage either, and it doesn't show the `Webview` fullscreen so it won't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the step #2 the code evaluates in an empty `about:blank` page. Hence, saved property is assigned to `about:blank` address and not `SOMEURL` address. Try evaluating #2 only after the `Future` returned by `.launch(...)` completes.

e.g.

```dart
flutterWebviewPlugin.launch("https://SOMEURL",
  withLocalStorage: true,
  withJavascript: true
).whenComplete(() {
  final res = flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("(function() { try { window.localStorage.setItem('token', 'SOMETOKEN'); } catch (err) { return err; } })();");
  // Wrapped `setItem` into a func that would return some helpful info in case it throws.
  print("Eval result: $res");
});
```

Comment: Can you help me with this.