# Local Storage property does not work in Flutter Webview Plug-in

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, local-storage

I want to set some key&value pairs in **local storage** of my WebView in my flutter app. I am using the library called [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin).

I am aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960945/flutter-webivew-how-to-set-local-storage).

Eventually i want to set a token, in order to reach a authentication-required URL directly, which is stored as 'jwt_token' in Chrome's local storage.

The library i use provides a `withLocalStorage` property, and a `evalJavascript` method:

```
flutterWebviewPlugin
        .launch("SOME_URL",
            withLocalStorage: true, withJavascript: true,)
        .whenComplete(() {
      flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'key')");
      flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("alert(window.localStorage.getItem('key'))");
      flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript("alert('test alert')");
```

After running the code above the "test alert" pops in my webview browser, which indicates that `evalJavascript` method is working correctly, but the prior alert with the `localStorage.getItem` method does not pop. I have tried with and without window object, all '' "" combinations and the result is the same. I cannot set information in my local storage with this JS method. Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

`localStorage` feature is enabled by default!

Here is a quick example that sets and retrieve a `localStorage` value when the page stops loading:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    initialUrl: "https://github.com/flutter",
                    initialHeaders: {},
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      _webViewController = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) async {
                      await controller.evaluateJavascript(source: "window.localStorage.setItem('key', 'localStorage value!')");
                      await controller.evaluateJavascript(source: "alert(window.localStorage.getItem('key'))");
                    },
                  ))
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Lorenzo, is the plugin supports even after reloading the url, previously set Localstorage values will they stay same or do we have to set the storage again after reloading.
Thanks !!

Comment: It's JavaScript. LocalStorage values remains also when you leave the webpage, instead, SessionStorage is available only within the session. However, you need to check the official JavaScript API.

Comment: thank you, I understand it related to the javascript, but i tried with your plugin to load the url once after setting the LocalStorage then did the reload part,

Comment: For any problem, open an issue to the GitHub repository. Thanks

Comment: on IOS, is there anyway to set it before, while the page is loading? on load complete the entire page has loaded. And if it does not have the required values, it gets redirected.

Comment: I am facing an issue with flutter_inappwebview. On IOS onLoadStop only called once. There is an open ticket on github repository. https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1555