# Flutter webivewplugin how to set local storage

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, local-storage

My Flutter application flow works like this:

User logins
1-If login successfully, server returns a token
2-Set token to local storage in webview
3-Open Webview fullscreen to a specific URL
I am using this Webview plugin. The sample code shows that it supports local storage (it has a withLocalStorage option) but does not show how to use it.

I am aware of this [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960945/flutter-webivew-how-to-set-local-storage) [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960945/flutter-webivew-how-to-set-local-storage)

f I correctly set the local storage, the Webview would show account page; otherwise a login page (
That's Not What Happened)
Instade am getting this error

> I/chromium(13409): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token", source:  (1)

My code:

```
    void webwiew(token) {
    flutterWebViewPlugin
        .launch(
      "URLExpml",
      withLocalStorage: true,
      withJavascript: true,
    )
        .whenComplete(() {
  final res = flutterWebViewPlugin.evalJavascript("(function() { try { window.localStorage.setItem('token', $token); } catch (err) { return err; } })();");

  print("Eval result webview : ${res.toString()}");
}); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/pull/51#issuecomment-399468804 
You can wait until the first page loading is completed and then accessing `LocalStorage` with `evalJavascript` 
To achieve this you can use `onStateChanged.listen` and check `state.type == WebViewState.finishLoad`

```
StreamSubscription<WebViewStateChanged> _onStateChanged;
_onStateChanged = flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((WebViewStateChanged state) {
  if (mounted) {
    if (state.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
      flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(
          "window.localStorage.setItem('LOCAL_STORAGE','SOMETOKEN');" +
              "document.getElementById('showLocalStorageBtn').click();"
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer can you help me with providing more details how to use it thank you again ...

Comment: flutterWebviewPlugin is singleton, you can put flutterWebviewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen in initState

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it finally works. thanks.